# How to let Spark SQL and thift server see the same Hive metastore?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Using `spark-shell` and `HiveContext`, I tried to show all the hive tables. But when I start the `thirft server`, and use `beeline` to check all tables, it is empty there.

On Spark SQL documentation, it says 
(1) if I put `hive-site.xml` to `conf/` in spark, `saveAsTable` method for `DataFrame` will persist table to hive specified in the xml file. 
(2) if I put `hive-site.xml` to `conf/` in spark, `thriftServer` will connect to the hive specified in the xml file.

Now I don't have any such xml file in `conf/`, so I suppose they should all use the default configuration. But clearly it is not the case, could anyone help point out the reason?

Thank you so much.

---

When I use `spark-shell`, I see the following line:

```
INFO Datastore: The class org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
```

Does this cause the two(`spark-shell` and `thrift-server`) see different **hive metastore**?

---

The code I tried on `spark-shell`:

```
val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val df = hc.sql("show tables")
df.collect()
```

I tried "`show tables`" on **beeline**;

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it is because I don't know enough about hive.

Every time when running **HiveQL**(for example "`SHOW TABLES`"), if there is no `metastore_db` in the current folder, it will create one for me. `metastore_db` stores all the **table schemas** so that they can be queried.

So the solution is, run all the hive-related program in the same folder. For my case, I should run `start-thriftserver.sh` and `spark-shell` in the same folder. Now both of them can share the same tables.

Furthermore, if I edit `hive-site.xml` to specify the **metastore location**, it is possible that the metastore will always be in a fixed location, which I will explore more.